# C# - How to detect if specific program is running without executable path

Tags: c#, windows

i am working on program run on windows , that's show lock screen if specific program start running.

for example google chrome

they way i am doing it , take the target program startup path and add it to list , and then check each process and there startup path.

the problem is what if some one changes the exe install directory and run the program?
i need a way to detect if program run without using the installation path

Comment: check only executable file name part, not full path

Comment: thanks for your response , i have to deliver the project by tomorrow to my collage , and what if the user change the file name , like from google chrome to whatever.exe?

Comment: then you can try to use file size and/or file hash, but what if they install newer version and rename file?

Comment: or you can check resources embedded into file, chrome will have some distinguishable properties

Comment: exactly , this is the problem i thought about hash , but as you say what if update the version ?

Comment: you can also develop some kind of code signature, similar to what antivirus apps are doing

Comment: thanks sir , i will try search for this one

Answer (score -1):

after some search i found some kind of solution , that not easy to bypass by normal user

---

```
        public static string getoriginalname(string Path)
    {
        try
        {
         FileVersionInfo targetfileinfo =   FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path);

            return targetfileinfo.OriginalFilename != null ? targetfileinfo.OriginalFilename : targetfileinfo.InternalName;
        }
        catch { }
        return "";
    }
```

---

were you can read exe VERSIONINFO , like FileDescription,ProductName,OriginalFilename etc

and even if program moved from its install location or changed the exe name you can still detect it

- and if some one have better way please let me know.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as text

Comment: @KlausGütter , ok my bad . iam new here

Comment: No problem you can edit your answer.